# Research Topic Suggestions

Tags: research-process, graduate-admissions

I am applying for Postgraduate degree research but for that I need to submit a Research Proposal with the application and it is very confusing for me because I never did any kind of research before.

I have been a small business owner for the last 7-8 years and I want to do research in the same field (Entrepreneurship or small- or family-business related), but I just don't know how to narrow down and select a specific topic.

Can you suggest some guidelines to select a topic?

Comment: I've edited the question because asking for advice about specific research topics is out of scope for this community.

Comment: I strongly suggest discussing this issue with the faculty who are writing your recommendation letters; those letters are supposed to address your **potential for research**.

Answer (score 3):

> I have been a small business owner for the last 7-8 years

Have you run into issues/problems in those 7-8 years? Are those problems specific to your own business? Could other business owners have the same or similar problems?

Can you **generalize** those problems so that you can conduct research on possible solutions to those problems in **academic** approach?

Can you find the causes of those problems from **academic** perspective? How would you propose to do so? Should the government play a role or not? How could the society as a whole participate? Etc. Etc. There are hundreds of topics out there. Take your pick. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to work as a Postdoc in this field? The answer to this question (as long as it's a scientific answer and not reputation etc.) can lead you to a good research topic.

Nonetheless, thechniques like creative writing, brainstorming etc. can be helpful, but this is a bit out of scope for this platform.